# VAMT doesn't show clients waiting to activate until threshold reached?

Tags: kms

I'm trying to get the KMS on our network up past the 25+ activation threshold so that users don't freak out until we're finished deploying.  To that end, I'm setting up VMs on a vmware box.

When I type

cscript slmgr.exe /ato

on a 'new' vmware guest win7 ent client, it comes back and says cannot activate because count is insufficient.  This makes sense I guess.  However, if I go to our KMS server box and look at VAMT tools, shouldn't I at least see an entry for the client that I was trying to activate?

Thanks,